# Oracle: Dynamic Query: ORA-01704: string literal too long

Tags: oracle

**EDIT 2:**

After a small research I found that the problem is with long text value (more than 2000 symbols). I put values in single quotes in INSERT statement which I try to perform in "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE insert_query;".

Like:

```
INSERT INTO
tablename(
    field1,
    field2,
    field3
)
VALUES(
    '123',
    'some value',
    'long value more than 2000 symbols'
)
```

**So the real question is:**

How shall I insert long values correctly into the table?

---

I need to import a large string data from an external data source to an Oracle DB.

I have Oracle 12c (12.1.0.2.0)

**What I try to do**

> This is a simplified code just to explain my idea

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE parsedata AS 
    TYPE string_dict IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(100);
    field_name_list string_dict;
    query_field_list varchar2(3000);
    query_value_list varchar2(10000);
    insert_query varchar2(20000);
    --insert_query CLOB;
BEGIN
    -- Field mapping for data source and destination database
    field_name_list('source_field1') := 'destination_field1';
    field_name_list('source_field2') := 'destination_field2';
    field_name_list('source_field3') := 'destination_field3';

    -- Iterate over records in the data source
    FOR record_index IN 1..record_count_total LOOP
        insert_query := 'INSERT INTO tablename([FIELDS]) VALUES([VALUES])';
        query_field_list := '';
        query_value_list := '';

        -- Iterate over fields per record
        FOR field_index IN 1..field_count_total LOOP
            query_field_list := query_field_list || field_name_list(source_field_name) || ',';
            query_value_list := query_value_list || field_value || ',';     

        insert_query := REPLACE(insert_query, '[FIELDS]', query_field_list);
        insert_query := REPLACE(insert_query, '[VALUES]', query_value_list);
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE insert_query;
END parsedata;
```

**What I have**

> Error: ORA-01704: string literal too long in line "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
>   insert_query;"

I get the same error if I use CLOB

> insert_query CLOB;

**EDIT 1:**

I checked the length of "insert_query":

```
length(insert_query)
```

And I get the error when the length is greather than 3000:

> length(insert_query): 3038

Comment: Do you have any column in tables which is clob?

Comment: @Tejash I have 2 CLOB columns in the target table. But it's not critical, I can change it to another type if it's required.

Comment: This seems like it should work.  Are you sure that the error isn't happening on another, nearby line?  Does the `execute immediate` contain any operations, like string functions that might be throwing the error?  Native dynamic SQL in 12c should work with CLOBs of almost any length.  Is it possible the error is coming from the SQL statement itself?

Comment: @JonHeller Thanks for your comment. I had a brainwave! The error is exactly in line "execute immediate". I tried to test the last INSERT-query manually and I found that the problem with VALUES. I put all values to single quotes ('). So, at some record I got a value more than 2000 symbols in quotes. That is the problem! How shall I insert long values correctly into the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue occurs when you try to insert `string` value in the `CLOB` column with a **length of the string greater than 4000**.

You need to use `TO_CLOB` to convert string to `CLOB`, but unfortunately, It can also **accept 4000 characters**.

To solve the issue, You need to divide your string in chunks of 4000 characters and use TO_CLOB as described in the following example:

> ```
> SQL> CREATE TABLE CLOB_TEST (
>   2      MY_CLOB   CLOB
>   3  );
>
> Table created.
> ```

**Trying to insert a string of length 4282 > 4000 -- Error**

> ```
> SQL> INSERT INTO CLOB_TEST ( MY_CLOB )  -- inserting a string of length 4282 > 4000
>   2  VALUES ( '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   3  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   4  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   5  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   6  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   7  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   8  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   9  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  10  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  11  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  12  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  13  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  14  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  15  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  16  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  17  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  18  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  19  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  20  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  21  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  22  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  23  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  24  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  25  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  26  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  27  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  28  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  29  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  30  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  31  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  32  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  33  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  34  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  35  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  36  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  37  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  38  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  39  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  40  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  41  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  42  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  43  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789'
>  44  );
> VALUES ( '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>          *
> ERROR at line 2:
> ORA-01704: string literal too long
> ```

**Trying to insert the string of length 4282 with TO_CLOB -- Error**

> ```
> SQL> INSERT INTO CLOB_TEST ( MY_CLOB )  -- trying to insert the string of length 4282 with TO_CLOB
>   2  VALUES ( TO_CLOB('0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   3  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   4  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   5  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   6  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   7  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   8  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   9  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  10  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  11  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  12  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  13  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  14  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  15  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  16  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  17  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  18  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  19  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  20  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  21  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  22  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  23  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  24  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  25  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  26  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  27  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  28  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  29  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  30  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  31  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  32  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  33  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  34  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  35  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  36  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  37  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  38  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  39  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  40  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  41  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  42  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  43  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789'
>  44  ) );
> VALUES ( TO_CLOB('0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>                  *
> ERROR at line 2:
> ORA-01704: string literal too long
> ```

**Trying to insert a string of length 3670 < 4000 -- Success**

> ```
> SQL> INSERT INTO CLOB_TEST ( MY_CLOB )  -- inserting a string of length 3670
>   2  VALUES ( '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   3  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   4  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   5  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   6  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   7  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   8  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   9  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  10  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  11  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  12  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  13  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  14  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  15  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  16  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  17  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  18  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  19  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  20  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  21  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  22  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  23  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  24  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  25  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  26  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  27  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  28  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  29  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  30  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  31  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  32  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  33  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  34  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  35  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  36  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  37  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789'
>  38  );
>
> 1 row created.
> ```

**Trying to insert the string of length 4282 with TO_CLOB -- Error**

> ```
> SQL> INSERT INTO CLOB_TEST ( MY_CLOB )  -- trying to insert the string of length 4282 with TO_CLOB
>   2  VALUES ( TO_CLOB('0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   3  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   4  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   5  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   6  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   7  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   8  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   9  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  10  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  11  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  12  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  13  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  14  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  15  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  16  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  17  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  18  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  19  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  20  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  21  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  22  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  23  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  24  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  25  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  26  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  27  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  28  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  29  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  30  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  31  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  32  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  33  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  34  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  35  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  36  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  37  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  38  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  39  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  40  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  41  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  42  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  43  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789'
>  44  ) );
> VALUES ( TO_CLOB('0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>                  *
> ERROR at line 2:
> ORA-01704: string literal too long
> ```

**Trying to insert the string in two parts of length (3670,610) with TO_CLOB () -- Success**

> ```
> SQL> INSERT INTO CLOB_TEST ( MY_CLOB ) -- trying to insert the data in two parts(3670,610) with TO_CLOB ()
>   2  VALUES ( TO_CLOB('0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   3  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   4  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   5  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   6  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   7  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   8  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>   9  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  10  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  11  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  12  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  13  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  14  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  15  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  16  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  17  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  18  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  19  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  20  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  21  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  22  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  23  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  24  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  25  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  26  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  27  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  28  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  29  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  30  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  31  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  32  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  33  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  34  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  35  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  36  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  37  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789')
>  38  --
>  39  || TO_CLOB('0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  40  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  41  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  42  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  43  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>  44  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789'
>  45  )
>  46  );
>
> 1 row created.
>
> SQL>
> ```

**Note:** If you concate the two strings of length less than 4000 characters(resulting string length > 4000) then also it will not work and fails with error: `ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long`

So the conclusion is to use `TO_CLOB` with chunks of less than 4000 characters and concate the `CLOB`s using concatanation operator `||`

Cheers!!

Comment: Yeah, I saw such recommendations in other posts. Thanks, will do that!